# How to retrieve data from a json file using $Routeparams in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

[image]

i'm facing problem to retrieve the data using $routeparams i will decscribe my problem

/*Retriving the URL to redirect*/

```
  console.log($routeParams);
  console.log($routeParams.json_url);

    $.getJSON("./api-data/"+$routeParams.json_url, function(json){
        $scope.data = json;
         console.log('JSON--',$scope.data);
       $scope.processdata();
  });
```

/*Retriving the URL to redirect*/

this is how i tried to get the data but when i console it $routeparams having the data -> it is having the url in need
but when i concatenate with "json url" it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "undefined" in the console

i'm sharing my app.js

### app.js

```
App.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider, $routeParams) {

            $routeProvider

    .when('/base-product/:json_url?', {
                    templateUrl :'templates/base_product.html',
                    controller  :'BaseProductController'
                })
```

### my menu.html

this is the menu i have when i click on the particular link in this menu it should redirect to the associated json file dynamically

```
<ul id="submenu-2" class="collapse" >
                            <span ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">
                            <li><a href="#base-product?{{item.path}}" > {{item.title}}</a></li>
                            </span>

                        </ul>
```

my action.json will look like this

```
[

   {
      "title":"View",
      "path":"actions/view.json",
      "urlpath":"view?segment=view",
      "apiPath":"api/view",
      "methodType":"post"

   },

    {
       "title":"Add",
      "path":"actions/add.json",
      "urlpath":"view?segment=add",
      "apiPath":"api/add",
      "methodType":"post"

   },

]
```

i wrote a factory to fetch the array values from json file (action.json)

```
App.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  var itemsFactory ={
    itemDetails: function() {
      return $http(
      {
        url: "api-data/action.json",
        method: "GET",
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
        });
      }
    };
    return itemsFactory;

}]);


App.controller('SidenavItems_controller', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function($scope, itemsFactory){

    console.log("Loading json array name is working fine and tested in console")
  var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
    $scope.select = function(item) {
      $scope.selected = item;
    }
    $scope.selected = {};
}]);
```

help me out with this ..thanks in advance

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham :- it is the the syntax .. if i remove that "?" the redirection and routeparams won't work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your url param is wrong and you don't need to use '?' mark. Change it to

View

```
<li><a href="#base-product/{{item.path}}" > {{item.title}}</a></li>
```

Js

```
.when('/base-product/:json_url', {...}
```